# What surface forms when you glue opposite sides of a rectangle together, introducing a half twist for both gluings?

Tags: general-topology

I'm aware that when you glue the ends of a rectangle together normally, you get a torus.  I'm also aware that when you glue the ends of a rectangle together while introducing a half-twist to one of the sides, you get a Klein Bottle.  The way that each of these things gets glued makes sense to me, and the homeomorphism is pretty clear.

But what happens when you try and introduce a half twist to both sides?  Is it even possible to do this?  I've been fiddling around with cut-and-paste methods to work out what this might be and I'm coming out inconclusive.

[image]

Comment: The real projective plane?

Comment: Aw, it is?  That's so boring.  Thanks, that ought to be enough for me to look more into it.

Comment: Why is that boring?

Comment: Note that unlike the torus and Klein bottle cases, all four corners of the rectangle do not come together by this gluing.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, the real projective plane might be something totally different from what I thought it was.  At first glance, I thought it was just $\mathbb{R}^2$ projected onto a surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the real projective plane. Its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) provides diagrams much the same as yours.